# NTFS Compression on multiple folders

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, windows-server-2008-r2, compression

I have been tasked with compressing certain folders on a network drive. The drive is formatted NTFS on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. The folders to be backed up are all called "Backup", and are several levels deep into the directory structure. I would like an automated way to set each of these folders to use NTFS compression.

Also, on some folders that I have set as compressed, it seems like new files added to them do not become compressed. Is this normal behavior, or how can I ensure that all files within each of these folders does get compressed?

Comment: [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976800.aspx) you go.  Combine that with a Powershell script and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Following Ramhound's advice, I did the following:

```
$results = Get-ChildItem . backup -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} 
foreach ($object in $results) 
{ 
   $name = $object.FullName + "\*.*" 
   compact /c /f $name 
}
```

Okay, it almost did the trick. It compresses every file in every backup directory under the current one, but it does not mark the directories as compressed, so it does not seem to compress new files as they are put in.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am missing something important, but I finally found that it would work the way I wanted by moving to the directory I wanted to compress (using cd) and then running "compact /c /s" within that directory.